# Corda - Implicit Contract Upgrade Throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: corda

Any ideas why an *implicit* state/contract upgrade would throw this?

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.demo.DemoState.(Lnet/corda/core/identity/AbstractParty;Lnet/corda/core/identity/AbstractParty;Lnet/corda/core/contracts/Amount;Lnet/corda/core/contracts/Amount;Lnet/corda/core/contracts/UniqueIdentifier;ILkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V

Steps taken

1. Deploy nodes with state/contract version 1
2. Start all nodes
3. Issue new state from A to B
4. Stop nodes A & B
5. Replace version 1 state/contract in nodes A & B with version 2
6. Start nodes A & B
7. Issue new state… *throws error*

Comment: Hey there - are you able to update your question with the following? The full stack trace and the code from the state?

Comment: @NicholasRogers It was my own silly fault. I upgraded the state/contract JAR in nodes A & B, but not the workflow JAR, so it's loading the old workflow, and the old workflow is trying to construct `com.demo.DemoState` with its _old_ constructor. Updating the workflow made everything work properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in my case was...foolishness!

I had added the upgraded contract JAR into nodes A and B, but I had omitted to add the new workflow JAR. The old JAR is therefore trying to construct `com.demo.DemoState` with the old definition of it's constructor, which of course no longer exists, and hence... `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.